# Swift: How to modify struct property outside of the struct's scope

Tags: swift, xcode, struct, swiftui

Programming in Swift/SwiftUI, and came across this problem when trying to enable a view to modify properties of a different struct.

Is there a way to modify a property, belonging to a struct, without creating an object for the struct? If so, what is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now, you're trying to access `showOverlap` as if it is a `static` variable on `MainView` -- this won't work since it is not a static property and even if it were, you would need a reference to the specific instance of `MainView` you were showing -- something that in SwiftUI we generally avoid since `View`s are transitive.

Instead, you can pass a `Binding` -- this is one of the ways of passing state for parent to child views in SwiftUI.

```
struct MainView: View {
    @State var showOverlap = false
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Button(action: {
                showOverlap = true
            }) {
                Text("Button")
            }
            if showOverlap {
                Overlap(showOverlap: $showOverlap) //<-- Here
            }
        }
    }
}


struct Overlap: View {
    @Binding var showOverlap : Bool  //<-- Here
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 40)
                .aspectRatio(130/200, contentMode: .fit)
                .foregroundColor(.gray)
            
                Button(action: {
                   showOverlap = false //<-- Here
                }, label: {
                    Text("Back")
                })
        }
    }
}
```